# What could be a good XSS defense on Google Apps Script?

Tags: security, google-apps-script, xss

I'm currently trying to develop an editor add-on with Google Apps Script for Sheets. A lot of code is JavaScript embed in `<script>` modules, and I have some code in Google's Google Script language.
I have some data stored in the DocumentProperties of GAS, but here comes the problem.

Since a simple call to `google.script.run` is enough to activate a server-side function with whatever argument you want, my situation was I could inject some malicious code simply from Safari Web Inspector by setting a Document Property from the client that is later redistributed as it is into the code.

To counter it, I am now doing a protection on the Google Script side, where every input to the server (and output from the server) should be composed of only alphanumeric characters, and the unicode characters +, / and =.

```
function sanitize(input) {
  var untouched = input
  var foo = input.replace(/[a-z]*[0-9]*\u002b*\x2f*\u003d*/gi,'');
  if (foo=="") {
    return untouched
  } else {
    Logger.log("Sanitize failed !");
    return null;
  }
}
```

With the only communication between the server and the client being either the initialisation on the webpage (`onOpen` method) or the exchange of DocumentProperties, is this barrier sufficient to protect the data from potential XSS attacks? If not, what should be done?

[OWASP gives clear indications on countering XSS attacks](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/DOM_based_XSS_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html), but first of all, what kind of XSS should I be worried building an editor add-on?

Comment: Where exactly are you inserting the untrusted data? If you avoid inserting untrusted data into all execution contexts,  chance of a xss is low.

Comment: Data can be found later in variables that go through sinks (so they are OK), but some are directly inserted in an `<img src=`, so it could be dangerous. Although the filter I put cannot let through URLs or `<script>`, it could let go other things that I might not be aware of.